# Enabling gzip compression on tomcat server makes minification of js redundant?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, webserver, gzip, minify

So I don't have to worry about including minification in my build process ?

Answer (score 3):

Minification removes redundant spaces, shortens method/variable names, etc.

Zipping is mainly searching for repeating patterns and ensuring they don't repeat.

E.g. I have just gzipped jquery-1.4.2.min.js (72174 bytes) into 24550 bytes. So most likely you will benefit from combining both.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, some clients might not send an appropriate `Accept-Encoding` header.

You might also minifiy for other reasons (strip out unused code, make it slightly harder to reverse engineer) etc.

As `Mindas` says, can't go wrong with both .